# How to set up Gravitee.io on Windows machine

Tags: api, api-gateway, gravitee

Is it possible to install Gravitee.io Access Management on a local Windows machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems to be no problem on installing it on windows for what I just read, just download the appropriate installer.
[download link](https://gravitee.io/downloads/am/)

hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try.

Comment: I managed to set up the environment by using the Docker Images provided by Gravitee.io. Therefore I have the 3 core components up and running, namely: the gateway, api management, the UI. But I have a problem with the API that I configured: namely I get 502 bad gateway when calling the API